# What is the time complexity of findOne and updateOne by _id in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Since _id is the primary key of a MongoDB collection, does it work the same as a key in HashMap where finding a key-value pair has a time complexity of O(1)?

For example, if I do

```
db.collection.findOne({"_id": id})
```

or

```
db.collection.updateOne({"_id": id}, {$set : {field: data}});
```

in a collection that contains one million records, does the operation have a time complexity of O(1) and finding the collection requires an instant time?

Comment: I think the answer is no, more like O(log(n)). The `_id` field does not contain any information about placement of the document in the collection/on disk. MongoDB will retrieve the document after traversing the accompanying index on the `_id` field. That index has a tree structure hence the aforementioned time complexity. What's the motivation for the question?

Comment: @user20042973 I am doing multiple operation sequentially on a same document. Using findOne and UpdateOne. I needed to make sure it doesn't cause performance issue as the collection gets larger

Comment: of course, i locate the document using _id field for each of these operations

Comment: Doing operations using the unique `_id` field is pretty much the most efficient approach that you can use. If you encounter performance issues as you scale then it's probably other operations that are problematic or you have outgrown the server hardware